# Sending a variable in python payload - http client

Tags: python, httprequest, postman

I'm trying to send a variable in python using a payload created by postman, I tried using {{}} and it 
didn't work for me, the place where I need the variable is indicated as VARIABLE_SPOT, please let me know what I did wrong in order to send a variable and not a text.

```
payload = "{\r\n    \"some_key\": \"VARIABLE_SPOT\",\r\n }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Declare Your Payload Like Below

```
payload = {"some_key": VARIABLE_SPOT}
```

> if you want to stringfy it run `json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: I can't use this structure

Comment: Why you cant @Charmer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *dict* and covert it to *string*:

```
import json

some_variable = 'some_variable'

payload_dict = {"some_key": some_variable}
payload_text = json.dumps(payload_dict)
```

`payload_text` is your `payload` now.

Result:

```
> print(payload_text)
{"some_key": "some_variable"}

> print(type(payload_text))
<class 'str'>
```